# Replacing the value of JSON based on key value pair with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a JSON with the following structure

```
{
   "name": "name",
   "id": [
        "abcdef"
   ],
   "input_dataobjects": [
     {
        "id": "someid1",
        "name": "somename1",
        "provider": "someprovider",
        "datatype": "somedatatype1"
    },
    {
        "name": "some_name2",
        "datatype": "some_datatype2",
        "id": "some_id2"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I am trying to achieve

in `input_dataobjects` if `datatype == somedatatype1` then `name = sonemewname1`.

I can use the index of the input_dataobjects since my json always has the same structure. But is there any different way to achieve it by parsing through the input_dataobjects and find the index to replace? I am using `jq` to do JSON operations.

I tried with using the index like `.input_dataobjects[0].name="someting"` because i know the position of the datatype always.

Comment: Please include an example output and what you have done so far in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest and perhaps most efficient solution to the problem as stated is:

```
.input_dataobjects |=
  map( if .datatype == "somedatatype1"
       then .name = "sonemewname1"
       else . end )
```

Comment: I think OP is asking for something more complex but I couldn't decipher his explanation.

Comment: @oguzismail - Yes, that's why I wrote "perhaps". That is, if it is known that exactly one (or at most one) replacement is to be made, then a more efficient solution might be possible, though it surely would not be simpler!

Comment: @peak : this is exactly what i was looking for. I did not know how to use map. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This was perfect for me to search and replace the value by searching for the key name. Beautifully simple answer!